# ImportJSONViaPost with array value for a key

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using ImportJSON script (more specifically, ImportJSONViaPost) by Brad Jasper and Trevor Lohrbeer, [ImportJSON on GitHub](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON). I would like to know how I can implement some sort of helper function to tweak the JSON object before turning it into a Google Sheet table.

The JSON object I want to parse looks as follows:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "alice",
            "transactions": [
                {
                    "seller_id": 1
                },
                {
                    "seller_id": 3
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "bob",
            "transactions": []
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "charlie",
            "transactions": [
                {
                    "seller_id": 1
                },
                {
                    "seller_id": 7
                },
                {
                    "seller_id": 3
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that `seller_id` can contain values that are not present in the JSON object, and that `transactions` can be an empty array.

I want the table to be able to operate on the `transactions` value. More specifically, one can assume that transactions can have a seller and a buyer, and the length of `transactions` represents the number of transactions each person was involved in, I want to replace `transactions` key-value pair with `number_of_sales` and `number_of_purchases` key-value pairs, where `number_of_sales` is the number of times `seller_id` equals own `id` and `number_of_purchases` is the number of times `seller_id` is not equal to own `id`.

In our example, I want to modify the above JSON object to the following before writing to a Google Sheet:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "alice",
            "number_of_sales": 1,
            "number_of_purchases": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "bob",
            "number_of_sales": 0,
            "number_of_purchases": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "charlie",
            "number_of_sales": 1,
            "number_of_purchases": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

The resulting table should look like:

| id | name | number_of_sales | number_of_purchases |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | alice | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | bob | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | charlie | 1 | 2 |

Is there a way to implement some sort of helper function to ImportJSONViaPost to accomplish the above?

I am not familiar with Google App Script so I am not even sure how to start. Currently I simply construct my query to not include the `transactions` key in the returned JSON object.

```
// Import JSON
var data = ImportJSONViaPost(url, payload_without_transactions);
// Write to Sheet
var activeSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetID);
var activeSheet = activeSpreadSheet.setActiveSheet(activeSpreadSheet.getSheetByName(spreadsheetSheet));
activeSheet.clearContents(); 
activeSheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

When I do construct queries to include the `transactions` key, the `id` that has multiple transactions gets written to multiple rows.

Answer (score 1):

If `data` of `var data = ImportJSONViaPost(url, payload_without_transactions);` is the value of `The JSON object I want to parse looks as follows:`, how about the following sample script? In this sample script, your showing value is directly used.

#### Sample script:

```js
function sample() {
  var data = {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "alice",
        "transactions": [
          {
            "seller_id": 1
          },
          {
            "seller_id": 3
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "bob",
        "transactions": []
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "charlie",
        "transactions": [
          {
            "seller_id": 1
          },
          {
            "seller_id": 7
          },
          {
            "seller_id": 3
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };

  var obj = data.data.map(({ id, name, transactions }) => {
    var temp = { id, name, number_of_sales: 0, number_of_purchases: 0 };
    if (transactions.length > 0) {
      temp.number_of_sales = transactions.filter(({ seller_id }) => seller_id == id).length;
      temp.number_of_purchases = transactions.filter(({ seller_id }) => seller_id != id).length;
    }
    return temp;
  });

  var header = ["id", "name", "number_of_sales", "number_of_purchases"];
  var ar = obj.map(o => header.map(h => o[h]));
  console.log(obj);
  console.log(ar);
  var values = [header, ...ar];

  var spreadsheetID = "###"; // Please set your spreadsheet ID.
  var sheetName = "Sheet1";  // Please set your sheet name.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetID);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, `obj` and `ar` are as follows, respectively.

  ```json
  [
    { id: 1, name: 'alice', number_of_sales: 1, number_of_purchases: 1 },
    { id: 2, name: 'bob', number_of_sales: 0, number_of_purchases: 0 },
    { id: 3, name: 'charlie', number_of_sales: 1, number_of_purchases: 2 }
  ]
  ```

  ```json
  [
    [1, 'alice', 1, 1],
    [2, 'bob', 0, 0],
    [3, 'charlie', 1, 2]
  ]
  ```
- When this script is run, the values of `header` and `ar` are put into the Spreadsheet.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)